# When would we want to use uneven subintervals in a Riemann integral?

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

The [formal definition of a Riemann Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_integral) is written such that you can have uneven subintervals and it still works.  Why do we need to generalize to the case of uneven subintervals?  Why not insist our subintervals are always of equal length, and $\Delta x$ is the same for all of them?

Here's the full definition from Wiki:

> The Riemann Integral of $f$ equals $s$ if: For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for any tagged partition $x_0 \dots x_n$ and $t_0 \dots t_{n-1}$ whose mesh is less than $\delta$ we have
> $$\left|  \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} f(t_i) (x_{i+1}-x_{i})\right) - s \right| < \epsilon$$

Notice that they have to reference the "mesh" in this definition, i.e. the length of the longest subinterval.  Wouldn't we get a simpler definition by just requiring equal subintervals? E.g [my version]

> The Riemann Integral of $f$ equals $s$ if: For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for any tagged partition $x_0 \dots x_n$ and $t_0 \dots t_{n-1}$ [with equal subintervals] less than $\delta$ we have
> $$\left|  \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} f(x_i)\Delta x_i \right) - s \right| < \epsilon$$

Or is there a use for having different subinterval lengths?

Comment: It amounts to the same thing. The standard definition is just more flexible, allowing for a wider range of proofs.

Comment: What about the case where $ f(x)=0 $ if $ x\in\Bbb Q$ and $1$ elsewhere.

Comment: when as a student can I first expect to see something where I need variable size subintervals?

@hamam_Abdallah could you elaborate?  couldn't we take even-sized subintervals where its irrational?  There would be gaps between the subintervals but they would be the same size?

Comment: note: $\Delta x_i = x_{i+1}-x_i$ and partitioning into equal or equal subintervals gives you the same desired result.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: The function in your comment is not Riemann integrable )it is Lebesgue integrable however, but partitions are not relevant for the construction of this integral)

Comment: If you happened to have a piecewise defined function, you would have the flexibility to make the partition be compatible with the regions of definition of the function...as you noted, not necessary; but perhaps convenient in some examples.

Comment: I think @hamam_Abdallah raised a good point though, which is that equal subintervals could risk thinking you could Riemann integral the rational indicator function when you can't

Comment: [Fermat used unequal interval lengths to aid in computations](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fermat+integration+geometric+series) well before Cauchy and [Riemann and others](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/8186/264) laid down formal definitions of integration -- definitions designed to capture what people had been doing all along before this.

Comment: For discussions and references about variations one obtains when restricting to left (or right) endpoint selections and/or equal-length subintervals, see these sci.math posts: [10 December 2002](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/NujAv9O_ezw/m/ZWf0evfh0gcJ) and [10 December 2002](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/NujAv9O_ezw/m/YKeTFjVU_cgJ) and [7 November 2007](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/UALfM26dlQg/m/8R8XAi_q9rgJ).

Comment: You need different subinterval lengths to prove the additive integral property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First example**

Suppose we wish to calculate $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} dx$. This is trivial if we already have the fundamental theorem of calculus in our disposal, but let's see what happens if we try to calculate this integral directly from the definition.

If we take a partition with equal intervals, that is, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we take $x_k = \frac{k}{n}$ for $k\in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, we get the Riemann sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \Delta x_k f(x_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}=\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k}$$
and since there's no formula for the sum of square roots it appears we are stuck.

Since we're bothered by the the square roots, it would be a nice idea to try a partition with unequal intervals given by $x_k = \frac{k^2}{n^2}$, because now the Riemann sum becomes

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \Delta x_k f(x_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - {x_{k-1}})\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{n^2}}=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k^2}{n^2}-\frac{(k-1)^2}{n^2}\right)\frac{k}{n}=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n 2k^2 - k$$
so we got rid of the square roots. By the well known formulas for $\sum k$ and $\sum k^2$ (see [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)) we get that the Riemann sum equals
$$\frac{1}{n^3}\left(2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$
so that taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ we get $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} dx=\frac{2}{3}$.

---

**Second example**

Suppose we wish to find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1) \cos\left(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n^2}\right)$$

Noticing that $2k-1 = k^2 - (k-1)^2$, the limit equals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2 - (k-1)^2}{n^2} \cos\left(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n^2}\right) = \frac{2}{\pi} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n^2} - \frac{\pi (k-1)^2}{2n^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n^2}\right)$$
Denoting $x_k = \frac{\pi k^2}{2n^2}$ we see that this is
$\frac{2}{\pi} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(x_k - x_{k-1}\right)\cos\left(x_k \right)$. Aside for $\frac{2}{\pi}$ this is the limit of a Riemann sum for $f(x)=\cos x$ on the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so it equals $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos x dx$ since we know $f(x)=\cos x$ is integrable. By the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(x)dx = 1$, so that the limit of the whole expression equals $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Without knowing that Riemann sums of integrable functions converge to the same value (the integral) regardless of how we partition the domain of integration, this limit would probably be very hard to calculate.

Comment: Assuming we did already have the fundamental theorem of calculus, would there still be cases where we'd want to utilize uneven intervals?

Comment: @bgcode One example I can think of is that sometimes we are given some limit and in order to calculate it we interpret it as an appropriate Riemann sum of some integrable function. Are you familiar with this type of exercise? The idea is that after we interpret it as the limit of a Riemann sum then we note that the function is integrable (usually because it is continuous) and so we find the limit using the fundamental theorem of calculus. It is definitely conceivable that such a limit would match a Riemann sum with intervals of unequal lengths.

Comment: Moreover, it seems that purely from a theoretical perspective it is definitely satisfying to know that if we've shown that a function is integrable (for instance because it is continuous) then no matter how we split its domain into subintervals (whether of equal lengths or not) the Riemann sum is going to converge to the same value.

Comment: It seems to trivially follow from the equal interval case that you could mix it with bigger intervals and it would still work?  Since you could always slice things into a common divisor, and create a new equal interval thing with smaller intervals that filled in both.

Comment: @bgcode It's not as trivial as it seems, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Similar_concepts "Another popular restriction is the use of regular subdivisions of an interval .. alone this restriction does not impose a problem, but the reasoning required to see this fact is more difficult than in the case of left-hand and right-hand Riemann sums. However, combining these restrictions, so that one uses only left-hand or right-hand Riemann sums on regularly divided intervals, is dangerous .. under these conditions the indicator function $I_{\mathbb{Q}}$ will appear to be integrable"

Comment: Wow, the rational indicator function actually makes you realize that you've only been taking rational bounds on equal subintervals no matter how far you zoom in!  So the restriction makes sense to allow you to handle such rule breaking functions?

Comment: @bgcode I added a second example, where to calculate a limit we need to use a Riemann sum with an uneven partition. I'm not sure what you mean about the restriction allowing us to handle such functions, if you want we can continue in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133732/discussion-between-bgcode-and-snaw).